# Laravel 4.2 View caching issue

Tags: php, laravel

I am updating view and refreshing the route which is rendering that particular view. But it loads previous view. After multiple refresh I get the latest updated view. Can you please explain me in detail how my view should not be cached and i should get updated view only.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 4.2 you can't run the command `php artisan cache:clear` to remove the views. That's because they aren't *cached*, their *compiled*.

Laravel 5.1 and greater implemented the command `php artisan view:clear` to clear compiled views, but here is a custom command you can use in Laravel 4.2 to clear them:

https://gist.github.com/cjonstrup/8228165

Otherwise, just delete all the files in `app/storage/views` and views will be re-compiled.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to set debug to true, open your browser dev tools and check the option to don't cache pages when dev tools are opened and finally, give 777 permissions to you storage folder (I don't remember the name of the folder in Laravel 4.2) where compiled views are stored as sometimes the system can't write on that location.
I think it should be enough for you to get the view updated on refresh.